# Can not close an editor tab in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I remember when I click an editor in Eclipse, there would be a cross or maximize icon in the upper-right corner in the editor tab, as shown in the **right RED box** in the picture. I do not know what changes I did and could care less as the close icon is no longer there (in the **left RED box**).

Does anyone have any idea how to restore the close button back? I tried to reset all Perspectives, and clicked left/right buttons, but nothing changed. The Eclipse version is:

> Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
>   Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
>   Build id: 20160218-0600

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Try to restore the defaults in `Preferences > General > Editors`

Comment: That has happened to me before not sure about version restarting  eclipse fixed the issue for me

Comment: @11thdimension Restore does not work.  It is strange as an editor for a new open file is OK..

Comment: @shijiexu, reopen all the editors then :)

Comment: After using File>>Close all, I close all tabs and then everything is ok now. Thanks.

Comment: @shijiexu I take it it was just a transient issue then?

Comment: @entpnerd I do not think it is transient. I think I made some changes on the Preferences > General > Editors by careless. I think the suggestion from 11thdimension: restore all, close all editors, and reopen/restart is OK.

Answer (score 21):

In the file menu(File>>Close All), click the close All item. Eclipse will close all the existing tabs, when you reopen the code. The close button will come back.

Comment: This also fixed the problem for me where the tabs had no context menu.

Comment: I had to do this as well.  Seems like the issue still exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed E4 tools go to Preferences (menu Window → Preferences, then Appearance), there you should find CSS editor for Eclipse UI

Add the following piece of code at the end of CSS code:

```
CTabItem {
swt-show-close: true !important;
```

}
Restart eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the -clearPersistedState flag to reset the Eclipse IDE. This will open all editors and restore the original perspective. Afterwards your close icons should be back as before. Not sure what caused this, I have never seen this.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the Close button is possible via CSS, as example: 
[image]

To restore the original state you should

(1). locate your current css. In my case the path is:

```
eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.themes_1.2.0.v20160718-0743\css\e4_classic_win7.css
```

(2). Find and remove the CSS code to disable the close button

```
CTabItem {
    swt-show-close: false !important;   
}
```

(3). Restart